# Should I hire an electrician or handyman to move some lights?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling

I have 2 ceiling lights in Wisconsin, USA that I would like to move slightly (one to be in the middle of our table and one to be in our entry way). Both lights need to move a few feet. This is not something I’m comfortable completing and I’m not sure how complex this project really is. I did some research and it seemed fairly straight forward so I reached out to both a handyman and an electrician. As you can imagine, I got 2 very different quotes (handyman= $500, electrician= $1600). I want this done correctly of course but $1000 difference is what’s holding me back.

[image: Image of a lovely living room with two light fixtures on the ceiling]

Please excuse the mess we just moved in 2 weeks ago and still unpacking! But we would like to move both these lights to the right in the photo (the left one centered over the table and the right one more so in the entryway nook)

Is this project something I should go with the electrician or is this something simple enough I can go with a handyman? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the handyman, I'm afraid.

Comment: Post a picture so we can say more.

Comment: Electrician either doesn't really *want* the job (quite possible) or is thinking worst case scenario - e.g., existing cables falling apart or a brick wall in between old and new locations. And there are other possible variables. Can't tell without a *lot* more details - pictures to start.

Comment: An electrician usually doesn't want to be bothered with drywall/finishing work because it requires multiple trips to your residence. It definitely sounds like they gave you the "I'd rather not do this" price. Ask them for a second quote which involves no finishing work.

Comment: Was forgetting the must-be-licensed-if-not-your-house point. Though since country isn't explicitly specified....

Comment: Can we have your approximate location?   In NZ, I can do this kind of thing on my own home that I live in, but not a home I own to rent out nor someone else's home for money.  However I could help my dad do it at his own home.   Location and regulations are important.

Comment: Once again, location missing means any answers will be vague - or not accurate at all, regulation-wise.

Comment: Hi all. So sorry for being vague—unintended just new to it all! I’m in the US (Wisconsin to be specific). While moving the table seems like a simple answer it’s really not a feasible one for the space. We also considered a swag chandelier however the way the lights are positioned currently would be very poor layout and squishing two lights too close. And great idea about asking for no finishing work!

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 15):

Someone not qualified as an electrician may not modify electrical power circuitry in your home. They'd also not be legally liable in the same way a licensed electrician would. Unless the "move" just involves drywall work and repositioning boxes (without modifying cabling), this is not a handyperson job.

The way I see it, you have several options:

- Hire a licensed electrician. Your legal bases are covered and you can sleep well at night. Get more quotes to ensure a fair price.
- Hire *both*. Have a handyperson open the drywall and deal with any obstacles. Have the electrician do a quick move. Then the handyperson can finish drywall and maybe hang the fixtures. This may save money.
- Do it yourself. Some jurisdictions allow DIY electrical work of a person's own residence. The thinking is that you'll take appropriate care so as to not execute yourself (immediately or at a future date). By doing some research into house wiring fundamentals and asking questions here you can be reasonably sure of a safe outcome.

Comment: This.  If you Don't want to learn basic wiring, though I love that part of the answer, at least learn to paint.  You can get this done by suitably qualified people for a price somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect, at least in the UK.  Anyone may do the work, but it then needs to be approved by a sufficiently qualified person.  Perhaps your answer is locale-specific?

Comment: It is locale-specific. AFAIK in New Zealand anyone can do electrical work but it has to be inspected before anyone turns the breaker on, or perhaps before anyone connects the breaker. The asker should say their locale.

Comment: I'd appreciate references before I revise my answer. I'm having trouble confirming this.  A [related post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/can-you-do-electrical-work-yourself-in-the-uk) implies the same situation in the UK as in the US, where unlicensed individuals may only do work on their own residence.

Comment: @isherwood: At least in some US jurisdictions, having a licensed professional "do work" doesn't necessarily require that all the work be done by the professional, but rather that a licensed professional *accept responsibility* for the work.  The media made a big to-do about how a plumber's assistant who became known as "Joe the plumber" wasn't a licensed plumber, even though he was an employee of a licensed plumber who would inspect and sign off on his work.  Note that in many cases, the easiest way for an electrician to be confident that something was done right would be to...

Comment: ...either do the work himself, or hire someone he trusts to do it.  An electrician who fishes some Romex through a wall cavity can be confident that it is undamaged and free of splices, but an electrician who is called upon to approve wiring that someone else fished through a wall cavity would have a much harder time ensuring that there was no damage or splices.

Comment: Again... references would be great. I'm well aware that persons such as apprentices can do work under supervision and sign-off. That's not what we're discussing here.

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking to have the old junction box obliterated and the ceiling refinished so there's no evidence of it?  There's the difference in price.

The handyman is simply going to extend wires 3 feet from the old box, and either put a blank cover plate over the old box, or mud over the old box ( which is a dangerous code violation).  Either way, the handyman lacks the licensure for the work, and probably, the insurance.

The electrician is prepared to go full monty and re-run the electrical wiring from the switch if need be, since it cannot be ascertained from photos which way the wires run.  The electrician may also be tacking on to hire a subcontractor to wrap up drywall and paint work. That will be a first rate mudder/painter because it reflects on the electrician if it's done badly.

Comment: "The handyman is simply going to extend wires 3 feet from the old box and mud over the old box". What makes you say this?  We don't know their intentions.  They could do as you said, they could make a junction in the old box and cover it with an appropriate plate, they could intend to tap into a neighbor's circuit and steal power, they could intend to take your $ and run, they could intend...  And I would have the same question about knowing the electrician's intentions.

Comment: @MackM We know their price, and we can make inferences about how much work they're figuring on doing.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my experience, I had called a handyman and an electrician for a similar job (installing new ceiling lights on a false ceiling and changing another one). However, the honest handyman told me it's always better to call an electrician for such jobs. It involves careful wiring/rewiring. Long story short, I paid less than 40€ to the electrician (as labour cost) plus some material cost.

My suggestion, get a quote from another electrician. Ask the electrician to break the quotation down into individual costs (how he reached the $ 1600 figure), and see where you can negotiate/reduce the costs.

But as a long term solution, I would say don't change the lights, rather change the country.